# File Move Scheduled Tasks not running bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, azure, cmd

I know this question might have been asked in other ways, but all the things I have read and tried had not yet fixed my problem, so I am hoping to get some help here with context to my issue.

The problem:
I need to move files from a local drive to a network drive (the network drive is a SharePoint mapped library) on my server in Windows Azure (don't think the azure part matters, but it provides context).

My thought was to schedule a task that will run a bat file to move the files I need moved and do so frequently (every 5 to 10 minutes).  The batch file I have created does what I need it to when I manually run the batch file but not when the task runs it.

Here is the batch file:

```
echo Write log file > LogStart.txt
C:\Windows\System32\robocopy.exe "\\PCICSWKS001\D$\ToBeMoved" "V:" /s /e /MOV /r:0 /W:0
echo Write log file > LogEnd.txt
```

You can see that it writes a log file before and after running robocopy.exe.
When the task runs it does write both of these log files so I know that the batch file is at least running.
You can also see that I have tried using the UNC path for the drive in the source, that is because I was reading that the task scheduler might not be able to pick up properly on the drive letters. When I put the machine name in for the destination and run the batch file myself or with the scheduler it errors.

Here is the action taken by the task:

[image: 1]

Here is the task general tab

[image: 2]

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: add `>logcopy.txt 2>&1` to your `robocopy` line and check it's output

Comment: There are two errors that I receive
                              
First:
  ERROR 3 (0x00000003) Getting File System Type of Destination V:\
  The system cannot find the path specified.
     Source : \\PCICSWKS001\D$\ToBeMoved\
       Dest - V:\
      Files : *.*
  Options : *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /MOV /R:0 /W:0 
  
Then:
  ERROR 3 (0x00000003) Creating Destination Directory V:\
  The system cannot find the path specified.
    Any assistance would be appreciated.   Thanks!

Comment: `Error ... Getting File System Type of Destination V:\ The system cannot find the path specified`. May it be, that `V:` is not connected when started via TaskScheduler? Try a `net use v: \\server\path` inside your batchfile. (preferably with logging to a file again to check the output)

Answer (score 0):

I had that same error with Robocopy after a few times of running it:

> ERROR 3 (0x00000003) Getting File System Type of Destination

I think it has to do with how robocopy scans the destination when it has a fair amount of files on it. It worked fine when I started the copy job and the Azure destination was empty.

Anyway, I think you should try to use the [AzCopy command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy) as that should be less error prone and faster since it was designed for this kind of thing. It's command line switches are similar to robocopy so it should feel pretty familiar.